# Setting minimum buffer size

Tags: c, buffer

I noticed something when I used the setvbuf () function to set the file processing buffer. If I don't use a buffer size of 256 or higher, I get strange symbols when I try to print the buffer. However, if I use 256 sizes for the buffer, I get the correct char representation of up to 8 characters. I've done research on this problem, but I guess I couldn't find my answer because of my lack of knowledge.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 8 //Below 256
int main(void)
{
 char buffer[SIZE];

 FILE *fp = fopen("name.txt","w");    
 setvbuf(fp,buffer,_IOFBF,SIZE);
 fputs("a",fp);
 printf("%s\n",buffer);
 fclose(fp);
 return 0;
}
```

Expected Output

```
a
```

Actual Output

```
a!'^//Something like this.
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and show us the actual and expected output.

Comment: It could be a bug in the C library, or you might be doing something wrong. It's hard to tell unless you show the code you are using to set up the buffer. I don't know what your "correct char representation of up to 8 characters" refers to. Do you mean UTF-8 sequences?

Comment: `fprintf(buffer);` is definitely incorrect. Did you mean `printf(buffer);`? That is also incorrect, because the first parameter should be a null-terminated printf format string.

Comment: @IanAbbott My fault.

Comment: Your buffer does not contain a null-terminated string.

Comment: Why are you trying to print contents of the buffer anyway?  Gerhardh is correct.  There is no null terminator which is why printing it looks odd.  If you plan on turning the contents of the file into a string to be printed at some point you may want to add one at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the buffer passed to `setvbuf` are indeterminate at any time (see [7.21.5.6/2 in C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.6p2) or [cppreference page on setvbuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf)).  So you shouldn't expect anything.